# Android: How to make list elements with sublist selectable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a ListView with elements that have a sublist with their elements.
This looks like this:

[image]

My problem is the following:

All elements should be selectable. But this works only as long as there isn't any sublist stored for this element (see element 'Abc' with green background color).
How can I make selectable also the other elements (those with sublist, in this case "Do Br" or "X Y") ? Note: The blank in the name of the element doesn't matter.

Code:

The main list:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewWithSubLists"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Entry in main list:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listentry"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#004400"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:paddingLeft="20dip" 
    >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/sublistView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

your requirement problem can be solved by using [expandable lists](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

[try this guide for expandable lists](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-game-programming/simple-expandable-list-example/)

You can also try using your own custom adapter by extending the class with [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

```
Override the method
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

to add events in your sublists.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I already thought about using that, but this has the disadvantage that you don't see the top elements of the sublist without clicking anything. That's one of my main goals.

Comment: Try this method from ExpandableListView in your onResume method
    public boolean expandGroup (int groupPos);

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#expandGroup(int)